# Printing out a Core Data boolean array returns a new line character

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

I have an entity in my Core Data model, one of which is an array of booleans called isChecked. In my code where I set and save the entity's values, I have the following piece of code.

```
task.isChecked = [Bool]()

   for index in 0..<endDate!.interval(ofComponent: .day, fromDate: Date()){
       print("checking task")
       task.isChecked!.append(false)
   }
```

Don't worry about `endDate!.interval(ofComponent: .day, fromDate: Date())`, as I have verified that that the loop runs.

However, later when I print the description of the entity, I get the following: `isChecked = "(\n    0,\n    0,\n    0\n)";`. This is what I get when the loop runs three times. Could someone explain what I can do and why it isn't able to print booleans?

Comment: What's the problem if you get the description in that form?

Comment: @OOPer It is just hard to read, and I am unsure if the values are correct because I can't read them.

Comment: It's a format used by `NSArray` (Core Data internally uses `NSArray`) and `NSArray` holds Bool contents as `NSNumber`. So, no need to worry about the content. Do you want to make some effort for debugging output?

Comment: @OOPer yes, I want to be able to check the values.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was missing something important. Core Data does not support arrays natively, how have you made your `isChecked` attribute as `[Bool]`?

Comment: @OOPer the attribute is set as a transformable.

Comment: My words above depends on your transformable is working well. Is that all right?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the debugDescription of your task entity and replace with something more meaningful.

```
Override debugDescription: String {
    Return self.isChecked
}
```

And in the description you could loop over the array and see if that helps with the debug printing